# How can I connect to a running node program with my repl

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript

I am using Bodil Stokkes node repl https://github.com/bodil/cljs-noderepl. Starting it is very easy. Just as described in the docs.

Now I'd like to connect my running node program to the repl. However I can't figure out how to do that. Can anybody give me a step by step instruction.

What I want to do is

1. `node out/main.js`  => starts my node process
2. `lein trampoline noderepl` => this should somehow connect to the process in main.js

Optionally I'd be happy if I could start/access my main program from within the node-repl.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Vantage.js](https://github.com/dthree/vantage). It let's you connect into live Node apps on the fly. This looks like what you're trying to do.

*Disclaimer: I made it.*